# How to select datas that doesnt match in another column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, where-clause

So i have this table A:

```
color        ID       MODEL
-----------------------------
red        | 10   |   HONDA
blue       | 10   |   TOYOTA
red        | 15   |   ISUZU
red        | 30   |   MITSUBISHI
red        | 5    |   HONDA
blue       | 5    |   SUBARU
orange     | 10   |   HYUNDAI
black      | 40   |   CHRYSLER
```

i'd like to get all red and blue that does not have the same id with each other

So my expected result is:

```
color  ID
------------
red  | 15
red  | 30
```

Comment: But there is another 30... yellow

Comment: @robin - Check all the answers and mention what doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hi @Utsav! When i tried your code it doesnt include the red 30 because i have a yellow 30 can you help me with this one?

Comment: When I am running it, it is including `red 30`. Check again and if not working then can you provide the exact query and output?

Comment: Why should `red,30` be included? The presence of `yellow,30` fits your current rule and so excludes it.  Is the rule you want to implement actually *select all the red and blue models which have an ID in red or blue but not both* ?

Answer (score 1):

or using an  `anti join`

```
select t1.color, t1.id 
from 
    tableA t1
left outer join 
     tableA t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t2.color != t1.color 
where 
 t1.color in ('red', 'blue')
and t2.color is null
```

Comment: Hi @schurik! When i tried your code it doesnt include the `red 30` becuase i have a `yellow 30` can you help me with this one?

Comment: you wanted  to "**get all red and blue that does not have the same id with another color**" why should red 30 be included?

Comment: edited my post. this problem kinda messed with me a little. i wanted to get all red and blue that doesnt have the same id with each other

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM   yourtable 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id 
              FROM   youtable 
              GROUP  BY id 
              HAVING Count(case when color IN ( 'red', 'blue' ) then 1 end) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to find rows with matching id but different colors:

```
select *
from yourtable a
where a.color IN ('red', 'blue')
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from yourtable b
    where a.id = b.id
      and b.color NOT IN ('red', 'blue')
    )
```

*Notes:*

- for efficient lookup consider adding indexes ( more distinct values means higher efficiency of tree traversal )
- consider normalizing your data with additional dictionary `color` table

Comment: Hi @kamil g! When i tried your code it doesnt include the red 30 becuase i have a yellow 30 can you help me with this one?

Comment: Well this is anticipated as per your request. _"i'd like to get all red and blue that does not have the same id with another color."_

Answer (score 0):

I think your expected result should just be red 15. Red 30 would not qualify because of yellow 30, which shares the same id. Check out my code:

```
SELECT t.id, t.color
FROM t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT id
 FROM t
 GROUP BY id
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) sub
ON t.id = sub.id
WHERE color = 'red'
OR color = 'blue'
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed the previous answer. Tested this and it is working.

```
WITH tbl
AS (SELECT
  color,
  id
FROM TABLE1
WHERE color IN ('red', 'blue')
)
SELECT
  t1.color,
  t1.id
FROM tbl t1
LEFT JOIN tbl t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
  AND t1.color <> t2.color
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
OR t2.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This query returns all the IDs where the COLOR is red or blue but not both.

```
select id , color
from  your_table 
where color in ('red', 'blue')
and id in (
    select id 
    from   your_table 
    where color in ('red', 'blue')
    group by id 
    having count(*) = 1)
```