# How to select datas that doesnt match in another column?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, data-manipulation

So i have this table A:

```
color        ID       MODEL
-----------------------------
red        | 10   |   HONDA
blue       | 10   |   TOYOTA
red        | 15   |   ISUZU
red        | 30   |   MITSUBISHI
red        | 5    |   HONDA
blue       | 5    |   SUBARU
orange     | 10   |   HYUNDAI
black      | 40   |   CHRYSLER
yellow     | 30   |   DODGE--take note of this as i have another ID = 30
red        | 10   |   HONDA--
```

i'd like to get all the model of **red and blue** that does not have the same id with another color.

So my expected result is:

```
color  ID
------------
red  | 15
red  | 30
```

Comment: You have already asked this question here and 5 people (including me) have given an answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495590/how-to-select-datas-that-doesnt-match-in-another-column/39502682#39502682

Please clarify what doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Utsav When i tried your code it doesnt include the red 30 becuase i have a yellow 30 can you help me with this one?

Comment: I think you should clarify your question in original post, which basically it is same question

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times. Such action pollutes the StackOverflow site and annoys people who spent their time on answers in the other thread, strangers who are trying *to help you*. If the other thread has not provided you with the right answer then please engage with people there, address their comments and/or edit your question to make it clearer.